# How to print the highest mAP in yolov7 from the training?

Tags: python, computer-vision, yolo

When I train yolov7 using the following command

```
!python train.py --data {dataset.location}/data.yaml --weights 'yolov7_training.pt' --device 0 --hyp "hyp.scratch.custom.yaml"
```

Output:

```
  Epoch   gpu_mem       box       obj       cls     total    labels  img_size
   100/299     10.5G   0.05475   0.02964         0   0.08439       243       640: 100% 15/15 [00:11<00:00,  1.31it/s]
               Class      Images      Labels           P           R      mAP@.5  mAP@.5:.95: 100% 1/1 [00:00<00:00,  3.27it/s]
                 all          15         178       0.465       0.607       0.509       0.155

     Epoch   gpu_mem       box       obj       cls     total    labels  img_size
   101/299     10.5G   0.05034   0.03036         0    0.0807       249       640: 100% 15/15 [00:11<00:00,  1.30it/s]
               Class      Images      Labels           P           R      mAP@.5  mAP@.5:.95: 100% 1/1 [00:00<00:00,  4.01it/s]
                 all          15         178       0.509       0.584       0.489       0.152
```

I detect using

```
!python detect.py --weights runs/train/exp2/weights/best.pt --conf 0.9 --source {dataset.location}/valid/images
```

How I print the highest `mAP@.5` from the training?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up [wanb](https://wandb.ai/) and added a Weave with the following line to get it

```
runs.map((row) => row.history["metrics/mAP_0\.5(B)"].max)
```